# Unable to get response object in ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

My ajax always returns undefined on getting response data
Here is my django view code:

```
   value= {'response':'SUCCESS'}
   return render_to_response('topics.html',
                             json.dumps(value),
                             RequestContext(request)
          )
```

And below is my jquery:

```
var options = {
    datatype: 'json',
    success: showResponse,
    url: '/media/'
}
$(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
function showResponse(data) {
   alert(data.response);
}
```

I have tried

```
data['response']
data.value.response 
$(data).response)
```

Nothing seems to work. I know I am doing an elementary mistake but I'm new to ajax. Could someone please point out my mistake.

Comment: silent:-may i see your whole ajax+jquery script....

Comment: I don't think you need anything more than this.
for is a variable pointing to an html form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got my problem.
I didn't have to do

```
  render_to_response('template.html'....)
```

Instead

```
  HttpResponse(json.dumps(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put a console.log in your showResponse function for a start?
So

```
function showResponse(data){
      console.log(data);
}
```

You will then see easily what to do.

Comment: I did what you said dumb of me not to try that earlier it seems my whole html page is returned as response.

Comment: Ok, so I guess now you know what to do :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use parseJSON method to parse json string. Below is the code you need to put in alert

```
jQuery.parseJSON(data).response
```

Comment: I think that's built in we don't need to call that explicit.

Comment: Did you try to parseJSON explicitly?

Comment: And by the way I did try.
It gives me an error. Since the page returned was html and json cant parse that.